# Sublime - Command Ctrl + Alt + Down

Tags: windows, text, sublimetext3

I have a textfile with 20.000 lines and I want use the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> in all lines, but... How can I go fast to the final line using this command?

Comment: With 20,000 lines that's not going to be fast no matter what you do; what exactly is it you're trying to do? There may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

can use CTRL+END maybe
Sorry if my answer weird